Create Synthetic Dataset based on 5 number summary, mean, and sd in R
I'm attempting to replicate the model of a research paper and I want to see how the distribution of their dataset to my own. Naturally, I don't have access to their raw data but I do have the summary statistics for it. How can I create a synthetic dataset that corresponds to the following statistics:
min: 0, Q1: 0.1378, median: 0.1831, Q3: 0.2304, max: 1
mean: 0.1853, sd: 0.0831, n: 15404
The end end goal is to graph the synthetic data against my data to see how much they differ. Any help is appreciated.
I've attempted to create the data with rnorm but unsurprisingly any adjustments to one stat changes the others. Packages like simpop and synthpop require an existing dataset.

This will be very difficult with only the univariate descriptives. You will most likely also need bivariate descriptives. You could try requesting the raw data from the paper authors. You might also see if you can reverse engineer any figures in the paper or extract some of these bivariate relationships from their models.

what do you mean by bivariate descriptive? Unfortunately there's no graphics of the raw data in their documentation and and even with the foia I haven't been able to get their exact data.

I mean statistics that describe the relationship between two variables. One of the most common such statistics would be a correlation. You could also look for other similar papers to see if they have more information or even their raw data available to you.

I have made synthetic datasets in the past and used distribution functions as the foundation, check out ?stats::distributions for the range of functions in R stats.
Here I use rnorm() to get a normal distribution around the mean and sd. Then I subtract\divide the initial Q1\median\Q3 and add\multiply the desired Q1\median\Q3. Then cap the values at min and max. And finally I stretched the data between 0.305 (discovered experimentally to minimize effect on mean and sd) and initial max, to be between 0.305 and desired max of 1.
Drawbacks\potential improvements:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet - "Anscombe's quartet comprises four data sets that have nearly identical simple descriptive statistics, yet have very different distributions and appear very different when graphed."
Capping the minimum at 0, results in about 50 "zero" values records; these could be better served placed elsewhere in the dataset, potentially to help shift mean and sd further.
The stretched values on the right tail is hacky.

Code v0.2:
set.seed(1)
min_val <- 0
Q1_val <- 0.1378
median_val <- 0.1831
mean_val <- 0.1853
Q3_val <- 0.2304
max_val <- 1
sd_val <- 0.0831
n <- 15404
    
# rnorm does the hard work, and if you did not care about min max too much, would not need to do anything else!
synth <- rnorm(n, mean = mean_val, sd = sd_val)

synth <- (synth - median(synth)) / IQR(synth) * (Q3_val - Q1_val) + median_val
synth <- pmax(pmin(synth, max_val), min_val)

test <- .305
idx <- which(synth > test)
synth[idx] <- (synth[idx] - test) / (max(synth[idx]) - test) * (1 - test) + test


NROW(synth)
# 15404
summary(synth)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 0.0000  0.1364  0.1831  0.1875  0.2290  1.0000 
sd(synth)
# 0.08341817

hist(synth, breaks = 100)


